# Convert a nvarchar variable to hexadecimal and later to datetime: Error when nvarchar is less than exactly 18 characters in length

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run this query,

```
declare @var nvarchar(448) = '0x1d1a33c677c0000';
select CAST(DATEADD(mi, (CAST(CONVERT(varbinary(max),@var, 1) as bigint) / 600000000), CAST('1/1/1601' AS DATETIME2)) as DATETIME2)
```

It gives the following error:

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary.

But if I change the nvarchar to a 18 character long string, by padding additional zeros, the query works fine.

Sample:

```
declare @var nvarchar(448) = '0x01d1a33c677c0000';
select CAST(DATEADD(mi, (CAST(CONVERT(varbinary(max),@var, 1) as bigint) / 600000000), CAST('1/1/1601' AS DATETIME2)) as DATETIME2)
```

Result:

```
2016-05-01 00:00:00.0000000
```

Though I bypassed this by using STUFF statement. But I would like to understand this behaviour?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

The binary string is made up of hexadecimal character pairs representing bytes, so if you have an odd number of characters, then there is a character left over.

So

```
01d1a33c677c0000
```

is

```
01 d1 a3 3c 67 7c 00 00
```